# How can I create a random status changer within a cog?

Tags: python, discord.py

The goal I had in mind was that my discord bot changes it's status after some time to a random status I added to a list.

```
import discord
import random

from discord.ext import commands, tasks

class Status(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.client.random_status_loop.start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
    async def random_status_loop(self):
        status = [
            'Value1',
            'Value2',
            'Value3',
            'Value4',
            'Value5',
            '',
            'Value6']
        await self.client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=(random.choice(status))))

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Status(client))
```

I've just been following some tutorials on this and am still new to programming with Python. This is what I put inside a cog, within the main bot.py file this works fine but when putting it in a cog it gives me the following error:
*discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.status' raised an error: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'random_status_loop'*

Is there something I might be missing, do I have to add a specific attribute for it to work?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind you're going to get ratelimited for this. Discord doesn't like you spamming it's API and a new status every 5 seconds is too fast. Try something like every minute/every few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The function `random_status_loop()` belongs to the `Status` class, and not `self.client`.

Try `self.random_status_loop.start()` intead of `self.client.random_status_loop_start()`